# MIPS sb operator: other 3 bytes

Tags: mips, mips32

**`sb $s. i($d)`**

When the least significant byte of `$s` is stored at memory address [i+$d], what is the other 3 more significant bytes of [i+$d]?

Is it the sign-extension or zero-extension of the least significant byte at $s?

**Edit:** `sb` stores the least significant byte of `$s` into exactly **1 byte** of space at address [i+$d]. Thus, no extension is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sb` is Store Byte - *nothing* is stored at any other address.

Comment: except at address [i+$d] which is what I'm asking.

Reference: www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Comment: That reference talks about loading from memory - `lb` for sign-extension, `lbu` for zero-extension.  There is no sort of extension when storing into memory, higher bits in the value are simply truncated.

Comment: It also talks about `sb` if you scroll down. I understand only the least significant byte from `$s` is being stored, but when you store 1 byte into a 4 byte register. The other 3 bytes will still contain value. For example,  `lb $d, i($s)`  loads a byte from address [i+$s] and "sign-extends" that byte into 4 bytes to be stored in $d.

Comment: `sb` and `lb` are not quite symmetrical.  `sb` only writes to a single byte of memory, no other memory locations are changed.  But `lb` writes to the entire register, performing a sign-extension of the single byte read from memory.

Comment: Thanks, I just got that. I keep thinking since memory is incremented by 4 bytes that every "save/store" has to store into 4 bytes of space. That's clearly not the case.